# Vue: Get data from parent in <slot>

Tags: vue.js, vue-js-modal

I don't know if what I want is possible in the way I want to do it. I'm using this Vue plugin for modals: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-js-modal

I have a component called `ModalButton` that is responsible for triggering the modal:

```
<modal-button :modal-data="{{  collect(['account' => $account])  }}" modal-name="leave-account">Leave Account</modal-button>
```

As you can see, I'm sending `:modal-data` as props.

The `ModalButton` component is the following:

```
<template>
  <button @click.prevent="show" type="button" class="px-3 py-2 bg-gray-200 font-bold text-gray-700 ">
    <slot></slot>
  </button>
</template>

<script>
// @ is an alias to /src

export default {

  name: 'ModalButton',
  data() {
      return {

      }
  },

  props: {
    modalName: String,
    modalData: Object
  },

  methods: {
    show () {
      this.$modal.show(this.modalName, this.modalData);
    },
    hide () {
      this.$modal.hide(this.modalName);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

You can see on the `show` method which comes from the plugin is sending that data to the modal

`this.$modal.show(this.modalName, this.modalData);`

In my blade template (i'm using laravel), I have the `<modal>`:

```
<modal name="leave-account" class="text-center">
    <div class="flex items-center justify-center h-full p-6">
        <div>
            <div>
                <div class="text-3xl font-bold mb-2">Are you sure?</div>
                <p>If you leave this account, you won't be able to join back unless invited again. </p>
            </div>
            <footer class="flex items-center justify-end mb-24 mt-auto">
                <button class="px-3 py-2 bg-gray-200 font-bold text-gray-700 mr-3">Cancel</button>
                <ajax-button 
                class-list="px-3 py-2 bg-primary text-white font-bold"
                :route=@{{SOMEHOW ACCESS MODAL DATA}}
                method="delete">
                Yes, leave account
                </ajax-button>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
</modal>
```

Inside my modal, I have another component called `AjaxButton` which allows me to have a reusable button that handles ajax requests.

I need a way of accessing the modal data that was passed to the modal. I'd like not to have to create an additional specific modal component to handle this.

Is this possible?

Specifically what the `:route` prop needs to send is the `Account` since my route requires model binding. i.e it'll look something like `/accounts/leave/53`

Edit:

So I can do this:

```
<button @click="$modal.hide('leave-account')" class="px-3 py-2 bg-gray-200 font-bold text-gray-700 mr-3">Cancel</button>
```

(that's right above my `<ajax-button>`)

So clearly I'm able to access the `$modal` properties / methods. So there has to be a way to accomplish what I want

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simpler modal:

```html
<modal-button v-model="showModal">
Leave Account
</modal-button>
<modal v-model="showModal" caption="Leave Account">
{{  collect(['account' => $account])  }}
</modal>
```

Then `modal-button` will look like this:

```html
<template>
  <button @click.stop="$emit('input',true)" type="button" class="px-3 py-2 bg-gray-200 font-bold text-gray-700 ">
    <slot/>
  </button>
</template>

<script>
export default
{
  name: 'ModalButton',
  props:
  {
    value:
    {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

and the `modal` component will be:

```html
<template>
  <transition name="modal">
    <div class="modal_overlay" @click="close" v-if="value">
      <div class="modal_content" style="overflow: auto;" @click.stop>
        <div class="modal_title">{{ caption }} <div class="modal_close" @click="close">&#10006;</div></div>
        <slot/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </transition>
</template>

<script>

export default
{
  props: 
  {
    value:
    {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    caption:
    {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    },

  created()
  {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', this.modal_escape, false);
  },
  beforeDestroy()
  {
    document.removeEventListener('keydown', this.modal_escape, false);
  },
  methods:
    {
      close()
      {
        this.$emit('input', false);
      },
      modal_escape(event)
      {
        var e = event || window.event;
        if(this.value && e.keyCode == 27)
        {
          this.close();
          // All good browsers…
          if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
          // …and IE
          if (e.returnValue) e.returnValue = false;
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
}
</script>

<style>
  .modal_overlay
  {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 25;
    text-align: initial;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  }

  .modal_content
  {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    max-width: 90vw;
    max-height: 90vh;
  }

  .modal_title
  {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #F27935;
    color: white;
    line-height: 1.65;
    padding-left: 6px;
  }

  .modal_close
  {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 5px 0 4px;
  }

  .modal_close:hover
  {
    color: white;
    background-color: #00B4FF;
  }

  .modal-enter-active
  {
    transition: all .4s ease;
  }

  .modal-leave-active
  {
    transition: all .2s cubic-bezier(1.0, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0);
  }

  .modal-enter, .modal-leave-to
  {
    transform: translateX(10px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Not saying you're wrong in that I may have to remake my components, but this doesn't answer my question at all. Thanks anyway. I'd also like to continue to use the vue plugin I linked

Comment: Well, you can simply add a `ref` to your `modal-button` and access the data in `ajax-button` as `$refs.myRef.modalData`